# How can I scrape and save data in descending order i.e. -created

Tags: python, django, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I now have the ability to scrape data and save it to my database. But the problem is, it has the oldest first when I display it. I tried this:

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
    entries = [
        {'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
         'src': box.img.get('src'),
         'text': box.strong.a.text} 
        for box in titles
    ]

    for entry in entries.reverse():
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.status = 'published'
        post.save()
    return entries
```

But I got this error:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I also tried this:

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
    entries = [
        {'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
         'src': box.img.get('src'),
         'text': box.strong.a.text} 
        for box in titles
    ]

    for entry in entries:
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.status = 'published'
        ordering = ('-publish',)
        post.save()
    return entries
```

And nothing.

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
    entries = [
        {'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
         'src': box.img.get('src'),
         'text': box.strong.a.text} 
        for box in titles
    ]

    for entry in entries.reverse():
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.status = 'published'
        post.ordering = ['id']
        post.save()
    return entries
```

None of those approaches work. I feel like it has something to do with:

```
for entry in entries:
    post = Post()
    post.title = entry['text']
    post.image_url = entry['src']
    post.status = 'published'
    post.save()
```

Because I have an exact duplicate function minus the "for entry in entries" loop above and the ordering is fine. It looks like this:

```
def scrape_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
    entries = [
        {'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
         'src': box.img.get('src'),
         'text': box.strong.a.text} 
        for box in titles
    ]

    return entries
```

How can I adjust my syntax so that the order is stored and displayed in descending order?

EDIT: my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

  STATUS_CHOICES = (
     ('draft', 'Draft'),
     ('published', 'Published'),
  )
  title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                          unique_for_date='publish')
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            height_field='height_field',
                            width_field='width_field')
  image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               )
  height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                     null=True,
                                     blank=True,
                                     )
  width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    )
  author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name='blog_posts',
                             null=True,
                             blank=True,)
  body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,)
  publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                            default='draft')
  video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,)

  class Meta:
      ordering = ('-publish',)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

  objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
  published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
  tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the tag on your question, you are using Django. And I'm also assuming that `Post` is a Django model. If that's correct and you want to define a default ordering when you lookup `Post` instances, then you have to do it in your model class, by using the [`Meta` options *ordering*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#ordering). Something like:

```
class Post(Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    # Field definitions...
```

You could also consider adding a [`DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) with the [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) option activated, and sorting by that field.

Comment: @jslaurent I already have that in my model. but for some reason scraped data is not affected by that

Comment: @losee Can you add your model's code to the question?

Comment: @jslaurent I just added it

Comment: @losee I don't see anywhere in your code where the `published` field is populated from what you have parsed in the HTML. Either you need to populate it so that the ordering works, or you need to change your default ordering to `created`.

Answer (score 0):

The **reversed**() method is what worked.

```
reverse()
```

doesn't iterate

so my code went from this

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
    entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
                'src': box.img.get('src'),
                'text': box.strong.a.text,
                } for box in titles]

    for entry in entries.reverse():
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.status = 'published'
        post.save()
    return entries
```

to this

```
def scrape_and_store_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
    entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
                'src': box.img.get('src'),
                'text': box.strong.a.text,
                } for box in titles]

    entries = entries.__reversed__()

    for entry in entries.reverse():
        post = Post()
        post.title = entry['text']
        post.image_url = entry['src']
        post.status = 'published'
        post.save()
    return entries
```

I hope this helps someone